# Are there any "Zero-U" PDU's that allow for power management/remote power control

Tags: rack, rackmount, power-distribution-unit

I can't seem to find any PDU's (in general) that fit a 24U server rack that don't require at least 1U of rack space. (I'd prefer Zero-U) that allows for remote 'reset' of the power ports as well as monitoring features.

Can anyone guide me to something like that from APC or TrippLite? I'd be nice if it had 16 outlets (or so) and ran 120V. If it has C13 output connections, even better!

Must have Nema 5-20R to wall/UPS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on the dimensions of your equipment based on your question, but any in-rack PDUs will require at least 1U of rack space.  Side-Mount PDUs/CDUs like [These (from ServerTech)](http://www.servertech.com/products/smart-pdus/) are zero-U in the rack, but need to be mounted to the side rails somewhere.

The ServerTech products I linked to have remote management & monitoring features (though they vary by model & installed options). I'm sure that [at least one model of PDU from APC](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=70) must also support remote management & monitoring.

<s>If your rack itself is only 2U (where did you acquire such a diminutive beast?) then a PDU is probably overkill - Look instead for a [remote power switch](http://www.remotepowerswitch.com/) type device...</s> -- Original post corrected with correct (24U) rack dimensions

Comment: Well the Zero-U PDU's don't require me to take up any rack space (thus leaving me room to actually rack servers).  I'm working with a 24U Dell Rack, I don't have the precise dimensions at the moment but most/all of the Zero-U's I'm finding are too tall to fit vertically in my rack cabinet. *Edited top post to fix 2U rack to 24U rack. HA HA Comedy!

Comment: 24U makes more sense than 2U :-)  **  I think the servertech units will fit in a 24U rack, but it would be pretty tight (like probably full fit top-to-bottom tight), most zero-U PDUs are sized for full racks.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody makes a 'shorty' for 24U Racks. My present PDU's (no management at all) fit in a "Zero-U" type space, but they're Dell PDU's meant to go in this rack enclosure.  I figured *SOMEONE* has got to make one with management functions too for Zero-U spaces.

Comment: Working with a rep at ServerTech, he believes he has a unit that will work but he wants to speak with an engineer about the mounting requirements for my Dell rack. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well it turns out they do not believe it'll fit with the power cord plugged in. (Comes directly out of the bottom of the PDU)

Answer (score 1):

Are all your racked items full-depth servers? Most my drive arrays are only 2/3 depth and I've gotten away with mounting a racked PDU behind them.

Comment: A couple are full depth... I guess that'll eliminate that possibility.

Comment: this is what always kills me - 90% of my stuff is full-depth

Answer (score 1):

I know this was a while ago but Dell make various 21U OU mounting PDUs for this rack.
This is the model no. that gives 12 x C13 & 2 x C19 but uses L6-30 input on a 3Metre cable. H534N
The only ones with L5-20 all give NEMA 5-15 output 12 x 5-15 in the case of the J519N

Both of these are metered, there are no fully managed ones for 24U racks.